# Can I use tryParse output parameters to populate an array in a for-loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I've got a homework stickler for which I need another set of eyes. The assignment is to create a program that prompts for a Student's name, then iterates through an array of days (`String[] days = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};`) prompting for a number of hours studied each day. Finally, the program is to display the daily average number of hours studied for the week.

I'm stuck with the data entry method:

```
    public void EnterHours()
    {
         // entry area header
        Console.WriteLine("Enter study hours for {0} ", name);
        for (int i = 0; i < days.Length; i++) 
        {
            Console.Write("{0}'s study hours: ", days[i]);
            string dailyHours = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(dailyHours, out hours[i]);    // problematic statement
        }
        SumHours(hours);
    }
```

Currently, the `name` variable is a property that's already been set; `days` is the `String[]` above, and I've instantiated `hours` as `int[] hours;` with the same scope as `days`. SumHours is another method that accepts `int[] hours` as a parameter and iterates through the array summing the values.

When I run the program, the console displays

`Enter study hours for John Doe`

`Sunday's study hours:`

but no matter what I enter, I end up with a `Null Reference Exception`. I'm also getting the following warning message:

```
Warning 1   Field 'Midterm.StudentHour.hours' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null C:\Users\Dan\Dropbox\_MATC\ITDEV115\Assignments\Midterm\StudentHour.cs  11  15  Midterm
```

I've tried instantiating `hours` as `int[] hours = new int[7];` but get the same error, so I suspect it's something with the way I'm outputting the parsed integer, but I'm not sure what to look at beyond that to solve the problem. Ideas? Hints?

Comment: There's no point to use TryParse without checking its result. You will not know if the parsing didn't succeed.

Comment: Can you provide me more detail like the code you used to initialize `StudentHour` class, `StudentHour` class constructor?

Comment: Problem with assignment to array cell can be solved by introducing temporary variable.

Comment: If you declare  the int array as `int[] hours` you will get the null reference exception at the TryParse. If you declare as `int[] hours = new int[7]` then it should work. Do you have a different exception then?

Comment: It seems like a `Dictionary` would serve good purpose in this application.

Comment: Can you show the code declaring `int[] hours`, I have tested the code you posted and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you out:

```
        String[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
        Dictionary<string, int> hours = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < days.Length; i++)
        {
            int dailyHours;
            Console.Write("{0}'s study hours: ", days[i]);
            while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out dailyHours) != true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong input,must be only numbers!!!");
                Console.Write("{0}'s study hours: ", days[i]);
            }
            //if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out dailyHours))
            hours.Add(days[i], dailyHours);
        }
```

Instead of string array you could use an enum with those values.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some error with your declaration, since `int[] hours = new int[7]` shouldn't give you the null reference exception. Use the return of `TryParse` as well to check whether the input was valid. The following code works for me:

```
string[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
string name = "JLe";
int[] hours = new int[7];

Console.WriteLine("Enter study hours for {0} ", name);
for (int i = 0; i < days.Length; i++) {
    Console.Write("{0}'s study hours: ", days[i]);
    string dailyHours = Console.ReadLine();

    while (!int.TryParse(dailyHours, out hours[i])) {
        Console.Write("Please try again: ");
        dailyHours = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
SumHours(hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running fine. Here is the proof.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize the array "hours" before assigning a value into it.